# How to specify individual tasktrackers(nodes) on which a mapreduce should run?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

During the mapreduce job, the individual tasks will be running on random nodes, Is there any way to restrict the nodes in which the tasks should run ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hadoop doesn't pick the nodes to run the tasks on random. Data locality is considered or else there would be a lot of network overhead.

There is no affinity between the tasks and the nodes on which they run. Hadoop doesn't offer any such functionality.